# Moving directory after compilation of R

Tags: r, compilation

I compiled R in /tmp/R-3.0.0 and then moved it to /home/user/opt/R-3.0.0, then I got an error when executing R:

```
/home/kaiyin/opt/R-3.0.0/bin/R: line 236: /tmp/R-3.0.0/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory
ERROR: R_HOME ('/tmp/R-3.0.0') not found
```

If I export R_HOME='/home/kaiyin/opt/R-3.0.0', it still gives almost the same error:

```
WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME
/home/kaiyin/opt/R-3.0.0/bin/R: line 236: /tmp/R-3.0.0/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory
ERROR: R_HOME ('/tmp/R-3.0.0') not found
```

Is there a way to solve this, or do I have to recompile it?

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to do

```
 configure [...]
 make 
 make install
```

rather than a manual move.  This is a very standard process for source code on Unix system following the GNU conventions.

For more details, please see the manual [R Installation and Administration](http://www.cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html) that came with the sources.

There are also pre-built binaries for several distributions.